# Apache2 does not restart after enabling rewrite

Tags: 14.04, apache2

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.5. I enabled rewrite by typing in terminal

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

The problem is after typing `sudo service apache2 restart` I am getting

```
 * Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

000-default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/

    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Errors log

```
[Mon May 15 17:20:45.105432 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 23318:tid 139799949780864] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon May 15 17:20:45.105629 2017] [core:notice] [pid 23318:tid 139799949780864] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon May 15 17:29:27.789501 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 23318:tid 139799949780864] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon May 15 17:29:28.862943 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1192] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon May 15 17:29:28.863087 2017] [core:notice] [pid 1192] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon May 15 17:29:30.133713 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1192] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon May 15 17:29:31.240835 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1278] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon May 15 17:29:31.240914 2017] [core:notice] [pid 1278] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon May 15 17:31:07.210516 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1278] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Comment: Do you have both `mpm_event` and `mpm_prefork` enabled?  Can you give us the output of `apache2ctl -M`? Can you give us the output of `journalctl -xe` after you try to start apache?

Comment: Most likely a typo. `allow from all` should read `Allow from all` , CAP A in Allow

Comment: @bodhi.zazen `allow` is not wrong, directives in apache are case insensitive.

Comment: Well I am assuming there must be some typo to give the config test error "Action 'configtest' failed."

Answer (score -1):

Open apache2.conf

```
nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and change None to All

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then Restart Apache

```
service apache2 restart
```

Note: No need to change in 000-default.conf file

Comment: This change is not a good idea. Also, this wouldn't cause the configtest to fail.